# PDCurses missing seperator error in Cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin, pdcurses

I've been trying to get PDCurses in Visual Studio 2015 for 2 days now and I'm still having trouble. The best solution I found was downloading Cygwin and using the make file. When I call makefile I resieve a seperator.

```
$ make -f vcwin32.mak WIDE=Y
vcwin32.mak:10: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

When I view file, these are the first 15 lines.

```
# Visual C++ NMakefile for PDCurses library - Win32 VC++ 2.0+
#
# Usage: nmake -f [path\]vcwin32.mak [DEBUG=] [DLL=] [WIDE=] [UTF8=] [target]
#
# where target can be any of:
# [all|demos|pdcurses.lib|testcurs.exe...]

O = obj

!ifndef PDCURSES_SRCDIR
PDCURSES_SRCDIR = ..
!endif

!include $(PDCURSES_SRCDIR)\version.mif
!include $(PDCURSES_SRCDIR)\libobjs.mif
```

Line 10:

```
!ifndef PDCURSES_SRCDIR
```

I'm learning how much I really suck at command. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The makefile is (given the name **`vcwin32.mak`**) for **Visual C++**, win32 (which uses a different *make* program, i.e., `nmake`).  It won't work with GNU make.

PDCurses's win32 dependencies don't include anything relevant to Cygwin.  Most people would use Visual Studio, which provides `nmake`.

Occasionally someone builds win32-applications with Cygwin, but you'd have better success with mingw (fewer extraneous libraries).